# How to display album art in my music player(Android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-music-player, albumart

I'm making a music app. Everything is going fine so far. I want to display album art along with the playing song. But i'm unable to figure out the method to do that.

Comment: You can use an image loading library like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Pass on the URI of the Album art and load it to an ImageView. It should load up your album art with ease.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the metadata from the media file using `MediaMetaDataRetriever` class.

Code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getInit();

        // Ablum_art retrieval code //

        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriver.setDataSource("/sdcard/audio.mp3");
        try {
            art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            album.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            genre.setText(metaRetriver
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            album.setText("Unknown Album");
            artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
            genre.setText("Unknown Genre");
        }

    }

    // Fetch Id's form xml 

    public void getInit() {

        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.album_art);
        album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Album);
        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
        genre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genre);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function(api>10)

```
Bitmap getEmbeddedPicture(String songPath){
    android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));

        byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
               //coverart is an Imageview object

        // convert the byte array to a bitmap
        if(data != null)
        {
           return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        }
        else
            return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), it makes loading images super easy and has some nice options.

Basically, you just need your imageView (or all of them and loop them and load each image) and the URI of the image.

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load(uri)
            .into(imageView);
```

Link to interesting and easy tutorial for Picasso:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149